# Can XAML used in WPF with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wpf, xaml

I have a question whether XAML can be used in WPF with JavaScript.

I tried to make it, but it seems that WPF doesn't supply XAML with JavaScript.

Then I searched on the google, but I couldn't find answer.

Please help me.

If we can use XAML in WPF with JavaScript, please let me know the way how to do.

If not, please let me know that it is just impossible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot combine XAML-layout with JavaScript.